# In a set of $2n$ positive real numbers there exist $a, b, c, d$ such that $|ad-bc|< \frac{bd} {n-1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $A_n=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{2n}\}$ where $a_1,..., a_{2n}$ are real positive numbers.
> Show that there exist $a, b, c, d\in A_n$ s. t. $$|ad-bc|< \frac{bd} {n-1}.$$

I tried by contradiction.
Then I considered $a_1<a_2<...<a_{2n}$.

So,

$a_2a_{2n}-a_1a_{2n-1}\geq \frac{a_{2n}a_{2n-1}}{n-1}, ...,
a_na_{2n}-a_{n-1}a_{2n-1}\geq \frac{a_{2n}a_{2n-1}}{n-1}.$

After that I summed all these inequalities, but this is not a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_{2n}$ be the elements of $A_n$ in increasing order, so that the quotients
$$
 \frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}, \frac{a_2}{a_{n+2}}, \ldots,\frac{a_n}{a_{2n}}
$$
are all in the range $(0, 1)$.

Then let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be those quotients in increasing order. Since
$$
 \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x_{j+1}-x_j = x_n - x_1 < 1 
$$
there must be at least one index $j$ with
$$
|x_{j+1}-x_j| = x_{j+1}-x_j < \frac{1}{n-1} \, .
$$
Finally, $x_{j+1}=a/b$ and $x_j = c/d$ with some $a, b, c, d \in A_n$, and the desired conclusion follows:
$$
 |ad-bc| = bd \left|\frac ab - \frac cd \right| < \frac{bd}{n-1} \, .
$$